# Require Azure Function to be updated through Azure Pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

Is there a way to require that Azure Functions be updated through an Azure pipeline, and not someone using the VSCode integration or azure functions core tools CLI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe that there is a direct way to restrict deployment by *method* (AZ CLI, Az Powershell, Azure DevOps, Azure Portal, etc.), as ultimately most everything in Azure goes through REST APIs, ARM templates, etc.

What you can do is to organize your functions into a resource group or groups, to which you limit Contributor/Administrator/Owner access to the service principal associated with your Azure DevOps service connections. Allow other users the ability to read/inspect resources in that group, but only allow the service principal the right to create objects there. You may also need to allow the managed identities greater privileges to operate within that space, but the concept remains the same - limit the autonomy of interactive users in the space where your Azure Functions live.